# Google Apps Script - good way to read and write user preferences from a sidebar

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I know very little, but...

I have a function that checks `userProperties` variables before it runs each part of the code. That's cool.

Right now I set `userProperties` at the top of the function, but what I want is to have check boxes in an HTML sidebar where the user can decide what they want to do. (once the user sets their preferences, I want that to persist to the next time they open that doc and not have the defaults over write it each time).

My question is two-fold.

What's a good way to have default settings in a script?

and what I really *really* want to know:

How do you hook up a checkbox to write to `userProperties`?

Answer (score 0):

The [Add-on 5-Minute Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs) includes a decent example of updating & using properties to manage user preferences. It sets the preferences as a by-product of running a translation, but that workflow can be easily adapted to be an explicit save operation.

Comment: Thanks. I see that, but I got a little lost at the jquery part.